# Sequence diagram in javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How to draw sequence diagram in javascript/HTML?
I've seen some charting library like JS chart, Emprise javascript chart etc... but those do not support sequence diagram.
Also seen JointJS (http://www.jointjs.com/), but this library also don't support sequence diagram.

Comment: HTML is really not designed for diagramming. I'd look at SVG instead.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [draw.io](http://www.draw.io). It's free to use and it gives you an idea what the [underlying javascript library](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html) is capable of.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [jsUML2](http://www.uco.es/~in1rosaj/tool_jsUML2.html).  It implements sequence diagrams as well as many other UML 2 diagram types.

Answer (score 1):

Websequencediagrams has an web API that you can call from Javascript. It can make some nice looking images like this. Here's a [link to the API](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/embedding.html)

[image: Example sequence diagram]

Answer (score 0):

I'd reconsider JointJS, or using Raphael directly (http://raphaeljs.com/).