# How to draw a sequence diagram in a HTML page

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsf, gwt

we develop a web application and need to draw a chart like sequence uml diagram. Is there a chart tool(any gwt, jsf, html, javascript, java, etc... solution) for this purpose?

NOTE: The graphic must not be an image because we need to select items and take some actions on click events

Comment: You can use SVG.
For more information see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620780/sequence-diagram-in-javascript-html

Answer (score 3):

why dont you try **canvas** of html5 ??

these guys have a library
http://www.rgraph.net/

i found one more library here
http://www.liquidx.net/canvasgraphjs/

here is a nice tutorial
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/

Answer (score 3):

I know one UML modeller based on GWT. You can check out [gwtuml](http://code.google.com/p/gwtuml/) as one possible option. Here is the [demo](http://gwtuml.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/GWTUMLDrawer/war/GWTUMLDrawer.html#Demo?DiagramType=2&)

Answer (score 0):

Use an image and create an [image map with GIMP](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-imagemap.html).  Click events are totally supported.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jsUML2](http://www.uco.es/~in1rosaj/tool_jsUML2.html)  it might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [draw.io](https://www.draw.io). It's free online JavaScript based diagramming tool that uses SVG to draw shapes.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [js-sequence-diagrams](https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/)
It turns text like below into UML sequence diagrams

```
<div class="editor">Andrew->China: Says Hello
Note right of China: China thinks\nabout it
China-->Andrew: How are you?
Andrew->>China: I am good thanks!
</div>
```

You can check also how it runs clickable and color filled in jsFiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/chetabahana/f7ejxhnk/35/

- Click a box will turn its color to yellow
- Click an arrow will open Google site